# The price of using infinite_defaultdict

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

This is for me a heaven sent:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> infinite_defaultdict = lambda: defaultdict(infinite_defaultdict)
>>> d = infinite_defaultdict() 
>>> d['x']['y']['z'] = 10
```

by [Raymond Hettinger on Twitter](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/343823801278140417)

Having that I don't see why we should do these anymore:

```
mydict = defaultdict(list)
mydict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))
```

etc....

But I may be wrong. 
Is there a case where you want to avoid `infinite_defaultdict`?

**Update:**
I tried to benchmark the time

```
from collections import defaultdict

def infdd():
   infinite_defaultdict = lambda: defaultdict(infinite_defaultdict)
   idd = infinite_defaultdict()
   idd['x'] = [1,2,3]

def plaindd():
   ddl  = defaultdict(list)
   ddl['x'] = [1,2,3]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print "Infd = %.3f" % (timeit.timeit("infdd()",setup="from __main__ import infdd"))
    print "Plaind = %.3f" % (timeit.timeit("plaindd()",setup="from __main__ import plaindd"))
```

Apparently infinite_dict is almost twice as slow than normal:

```
Infd = 0.632
Paind = 0.387
```

Comment: What about `mydict = defaultdict(float)` for purposes of `mydict[x] += 1`?

Comment: I'm confused: citing the V3.2.1 docs: "If default_factory is not None, it is called without arguments to provide a default value for the given key, this value is inserted in the dictionary for the key, and returned." shouldn't the idd['x'] produce a default_dict as value? It looks like it silently throws away the default_dict and let the reference of the value point to the list.

Comment: Ok, it does of course, as the source tells it to... :/

Comment: Interestingly it is faster to use defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(defaultdict)) than the extra lambda. And replacing the list with dict for the plaindd() closes the gap even further.

Comment: Do you really need a three level hash? How about a tuple key: `d[('x','y','z')] = 10`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the default value to be something other than a dict, then you should not use `infinite_defaultdict`.  For example, if you want to count items or accumulate arrays of items, you'll want the default value to be a number or an array.

```
def group_by(key, items):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for item in items:
        result[key(item)].append(item)
    return result

group_by(len, ['here', 'are', 'some', 'words'])
# -> { 3: ['are'] 4: ['here', 'some'], 5: ['words'] }
```